# Bitmap Text Background and HorizontalAlignment

Tags: c#, text, bitmap, alignment

I am overlaying text to a bitmap as shown below, I need to be able to set a background colour behind the text and also set the HorizontalAlignment (i.e left/right/centre), can anyone advise me how this can be done. Also note the text size can vary.

Thanks.

```
Bitmap frameBitmap = new Bitmap(streamFrameWidth, streamFrameHeight, 
        streamFrameWidth * 3, 
        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, pFrame);

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(frameBitmap))
{
    // Create font and brush.
    Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);

    SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    // Create point for upper-left corner of drawing.
    PointF drawPoint = new PointF(10.0F, 40.0F);

    //HorizontalAlignment.

    // draw the text
    g.DrawString(overlayText, drawFont, drawBrush, drawPoint);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the alignment of the drawn text by using the StringFormat parameter of the DrawString method.

- [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332kzs7c.aspx)
- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21kdfbzs.aspx)

Comment: Thansk, I used this in conjunction with MeasureString

Answer (score 0):

You probably need `TextRenderer.MeasureText`.

It returns the size of the text to be displayed. Combining the size of the text with the size of the Bitmap, you can work out the appropriate location of the text based upon the required HorizontalAlignment.

Once you know the bounds (size and location) of the text, you can simply paint a color to those bounds to implement a background colour before drawing the text on top.

Comment: No, don't use `TextRenderer.MeasureText` with `Graphics.DrawString`. They will not return the same value.

Comment: I tried with TextRenderer.MeasureText and TextRenderer.DrawText the font was blurry and also noticed for example Arial did not look like Arial in MS Word (but it was fine using DrawString).